# React router v4 serve static file (robot.txt)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, robots.txt

How can I put my robots.txt file to the path www.domain.com/robots.txt? No server is used, its only frontend with react router.

robots.txt --> in root folder ./

app.js --> in src folder ./src/

```
(...)

export class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/stuff' component={Stuff}/>
      <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
    </Switch>
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

If I test it locally, it works OK, localhost:4000/robots.txt opens the file properly in the browser. However I am afraid it is not case in production environment? Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Comment: Is your prod environment an npm build? If so, did robots.txt end up in the build?  I would also recommend using hash routing.  This removes ambiguity with static files mixed in.

Answer (score 7):

Just put `robots.txt` (and `sitemap.xml` if any) in `build` folder.

[image: see image]

I did this and deployed it to firebase and I can access `robots.txt` through `https://my-site.firebaseapp.com/robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml` through `https://my-site.firebaseapp.com/sitemap.xml`

You should follow like mine and access `robots.txt` through `yoursite.com/robots.txt`

**Note**:  If your `build` folder gets deleted before performing `npm run build`, then you need to again put `robots.txt` in the `build` folder.

**UPDATE:**

if you put `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml` in the `public` folder, then they will auto get copied to the `build` folder every time you perform `npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CRA (React) or NextJS, you should place the `sitemap.xml` & `robots.txt` file in the app's **public** folder.

[Official NextJS Documentaion](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/sitemap)

After you push it to production, you can verify it by hitting the url : `you-example-domain/sitemap.xml` or `you-example-domain/robots.txt`